# Best Way to Programatically Control IIS 8.5 & MSSQL in an ASP.NET Application

Tags: c#, asp.net, powershell, iis-8.5, sql-server-2014-express

I have a task to create an ASP.NET app which will control IIS and MSSQL 2014 on a Windows Server 2012 R2 box. By control, I mean on
MSSQL: creating DB Users, Logins, Assinging these logins to a DB, etc...
and on
IIS: creating apppools, new sites, virtual directories, etc...

In the past I created a similar test project by creating command line processes inside the ASP.NET application. That, I know worked OK with MS Server 2008, back in 2011.

Now there is PowerShell and usage of APIs increased, I wonder if these tasks can be done with PowerShell in ASP.NET app easier. Or, are there other ways of accomplishing these tasks? May be new versions of MSSQL and IIS has an API or a management library that I can include to my project and use without massing around with commandline and ps commands (That is actually what I hope).

My search on this topic results in many different articles which are all very outdated. I need a modern, easier solution if there is one.

Comment: Care to explain why the downvote? I know this question doesn't involve any code, but it's definitely programming related!

Comment: I'd go for WMI... to every single thing coming from the windows universe, there is a WMI class /  interface available...

Answer (score 1):

From ASPNET, C#, use the classes available from the namespace System.Management;

This is a tutorial of using WMI from C#:
http://blogs.technet.com/b/josebda/archive/2014/08/11/sample-c-code-for-using-the-latest-wmi-classes-to-manage-windows-storage.aspx

These are the WMI classes for SQL Server:

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms186452(v=sql.90).aspx

This is a tutorial for controlling IIS7 with WMI.
http://www.iis.net/learn/manage/scripting/managing-sites-with-the-iis-wmi-provider

I'm sure you can find some more information about a WMI provider for IIS8.5

Comment: I never heard of WMI before, but looks like the thing I was looking for. Will check the links first, then come back soon. Thanks Adrian ;)